# Ошибка в Delphi при вводе дробных чисел

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

> Дано действительное число A, не пользуясь никакими другими арифметическими операциями, получить A^13 за 5 операций.

Вот мой код:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a,b,c,d,e,f,C1:integer;

begin
VAL(Edit1.Text,a,C1);
if C1=0 then
begin
b:=a*a; // a^2
c:=b*b; // a^4
d:=c*c; // a^8
e:=b*d; // a^12
f:=e*a; // a^13
Label3.Caption:=floattostr(f);
end
else
Label3.Caption:='Íåïðàâèëüíûé ââîä';

end;
end.
```

Проблема в том, что ввожу дробь, например, `1,5`, и нажимаю на кнопку "Вычислить" и программа вылетает с ошибкой, то есть не считает. Как это исправить?

Comment: Прочитайте и осознайте, что говорится в сообщении об ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

видимо вместо "var a,......f,C1:integer;" нужно "var a,b,c,d,e,f,C1:double;"?

В режиме отладки нужно посмотреть в какой строке ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

> Дано действительное число A
>
> var a:integer;

Вообще ничего не смущает?